# Room database: click on a record and open a new activity

Tags: android

I have a **Room** database with customers. I start an activity where you see a list of the customers.

I want to click on a specific customer and start an activity, where I can see more details of the customer.

I know that you need to use the **OnClickListener** method if you want to click on a button and start a new activity. But here, my list is made with **CardView**.

How can I click on a customer and open a new activity? And how do I let the database give me the correct information of the correct customer, like: If I have a Peter in my list, how can I click on him and see more information about him? Do I need something like get(position) in a method to see the information connected to that customerID?

[image]

This is my list. Every card consists a customer in this list. But the cards are not buttons and they don't have a button.

Comment: Do you use DAOs and Entities?

Comment: @TheLibrarianCz Yes, I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a list of `Customer`s you need a click listener, like this

```
interface CustomerClickListener {
    fun onCustomerClick(position:Int)
}
```

Which you will implement in your `Activity` and will pass to your `Adapter:RecyclerView.Adapter`. In the adapter call this listener when a item is clicked.

```
class CustomerHolder(listener:CustomerClickListener, view:View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    //...
    view.setOnClickListener { listener.onCustomerClick(adapterPosition) } 
}
```

In you activity, which will implement CustomerClickListener, call second activity with the `id` of clicked Customer. Like this

```
override fun onCustomerClick(position:Int) {
    val id = customers[position].id ?: return
    CustomerInfoActivity.open(id)
}
```

Method `CustomerInfoActivity.open(id)` creates an intent that launches second activity and passed an id as an extra. In your second activity retrieve passed customer id from the intent and call database to get its info.

**Updated with Java version**

Create interface `CustomerClickListener`, which will be used to interact with recycler view items.

```
public interface CustomerClickListener {
    void onCustomerClick(int position);
}
```

Add this interface as a parameter to your `Adapter` constructor.

```
public class CustomersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomerHolder> {
    private CustomerClickListener listener;

    public CustomersAdapter(CustomerClickListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    class CustomerHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        private CustomerClickListener listener;

        CustomerHolder(View itemView, CustomerClickListener listener) {
            super(itemView);
            this.listener = listener;

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (listener != null) {
                listener.onCustomerClick(getAdapterPosition());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Implement interface from above and pass it to the adapter. Like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements CustomerClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        CustomersAdapter adapter = new CustomersAdapter(this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCustomerClick(int position) {
        // Get customer based on the position from the customers list
        Customer customer = customers.get(position);
        CustomerInfoActivity.open(this, customer.getId());
    }
}
```

In the `CustomerInfoActivity` add this static method, which will add customer id to intent.

```
public static void open(Activity activity, long customerId) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, CustomerInfoActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("CustomerID", customerId);
    activity.startActivity(intent);
}
```

And in `CustomerInfoActivity` get passed customer id like this
public class CustomerInfoActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //...
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent != null && intent.hasExtra("CustomerID")) {
        long customerId = intent.getLongExtra("CustomerID", -1);
        // TODO: get customer details based on customer id
    } else {
        // ...
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Alright, I'm gonna try it and I will post my results.

Comment: What do I have to change in this code (Kotlin) to adjust it for java?

Comment: public void onCustomerClick(int position){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listener.onCustomerClick(getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }
I can't completely write the method in the main activity. Is this the code I should write in it? But View v and AdapterPosition are marked red. The method is in the body of the class, not in the body of onCreate. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To implement RecyclerView onItemClick mechanism, you can follow this tutorial - https://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview-listener/ .

Comment: I went through his tutorial, but can't figure out, how to implement it in the main activity. The tutorial uses recycler.setAdapter but I can't write this into my code, it's marked red. Also, how should I implement your code with ID and intent into the main activity in java?

Comment: How do you show list of customers? With RecyclerView and Adapter?

Comment: Yes, with both of them. In my code, I have this:                 adapter.setCustomer(customer);

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I still have one problem left. When I want to do CustomerInfoActivity.open, the word open is marked red. Do I have to make a new method with open?

Comment: Sure, all add it to the answer.

Comment: So in the last code you wrote: For else-body, I added some code with Toast. But for the if-body where you have the TODO: Which method do I have to implement? I put this: intent.putExtra("CustomerID", customerId);
            startActivity(intent); but the app keeps crashing.

Comment: It shows me this error: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object reference. My id is in long, so do I have to parse it?

Answer (score 0):

Use setOnItemClickListener() inside your listview to detect item clicked by user and pass relevant data to your activity through bundle, like below sample :

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                     Intent intent = new Intent(RoomActivity.this, CustomerDetailActivity.class);
                     intent.putExtra(CUSTOMER_ID, listData.get(position).getId();
                     startActivity(intent);
  }
});
```

Hope it helps!